# Securely sending information from a web form to an email address

Tags: php, security

Is it possible to have a user enter information into a form on an HTTPS secured site, then send that information using PHP to an email address securely? How do you encrypt the email so it's secure between sending it from an HTTPS site and checking it via HTTPS email? How feasible is this and what are the potential pitfalls?

Comment: A social security number should be treated with the highest security, which involves **not sending them to email addresses**.

Comment: Good question, I think it should be generalized to "how to send confidential information securely in an email" or "how to encrypt email" to be of more general use in the future.

Comment: As everyone else seems to state, please do not do this. Sending info except from one HDD to another on the same server is bad news for us. People break into computers for this information so why would you ever willingly send it out into the open?

Comment: You *can* send stuff securely in an email by encrypting the content. The question is, how feasible is it to do this while allowing the receiver to decrypt it. I'd be happy if everybody could focus on this question.

Comment: People know their own SSNs and have no business seeing anyone else's, so what's the point in emailing one?

Comment: @deceze: Then this question should be accepted/closed, and a new one should be asked, removing the SSN context, and focusing on getting data from system to user via email, securely.

Comment: @Mike I removed the SSN context, since most people seem to have a knee-jerk reaction to that. Hope this makes it a better question. :)

Comment: @deceze: Was thinking it would be better to have kept the context, in case someone else was considering the same logic, email SSNs around. Then we could include responses with <blink>DO NOT DO THIS</blink>

Comment: @deceze: But you have generalized it to just "information." General information doesn't really need to be encrypted, so what's the point of the question? The focus is confidential information, all of which should never be sent in an email. The only personal thing that's ever emailed is a temporary password, emphasis on temporary.

Comment: @animuson Whether the information is confidential or not is not the technology's problem. It's just information in the end. The question is how to transfer *any* information via email in a way that is not interceptable by a third party. Feel free to add "confidential" to "information", it doesn't really change the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, email is one of the easiest things to hack. Do you know how many people use their birthday for their password? **A LOT.** As a responsible developer, you should never send anything as important as a SSN in an email. Period. It doesn't matter if your transmission is secure -- the person's email itself probably isn't. It's best to help people out by not sending it to a place that malicious persons can gain accesss to very easily. Do your part to protect users from themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could encrypt the email with [PGP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt) or [S/MIME](http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/smime/). These will require special support in your client to decrypt. Most webmail providers don't have this (though there may be e.g., Firefox extensions to make it work).

Other than end-to-end encryption like PGP or S/MIME, it really isn't doable, because of email's clear-text legacy:

- It is possible to transmit e-mail between MTAs using TLS (with the SMTL STARTTLS extension). However, there is no way to mark a message as requiring it. You can configure *your* MTA to require STARTTLS, but not anyone else's. (Note that unless you have root, you can't even configure your MTA.) The default and normal configuration of MTAs will *happily* accept a message over TLS, and relay it plain text.
- Its normal to add relays when needed. In practice, they are frequent. So your message may take a couple of hops before final delivery. You can force TLS for the first hop, but none of the others. You can check `Received:` headers to see how many hops a message took, but that may change at any point (and it may change from message to message for operational reasons).
- Generally speaking, mail while in transit is written to disk. The normal MTA process is accept message, write to disk, confirm receipt, send message to next MTA, wait for confirm, delete from disk. You can certainly configure your MTA to store these on disk encrypted, but generally that's not done.
- Once "delivered", mail is usually stored in plaintext on disk. Your web mail provider probably does so.
- If you ever use a non-webmail client to access the email, its very likely it downloads messages to disk, in plain text. Then you have unencrypted messages sitting on a random desktop PC. The MUA may even transfer messages over the Internet in plain text.
- Email is easy to access anywhere, from any machine. Especially webmail. It will be very tempting for you, or someone else in your company, to log in to the account the messages are sent to from random devices. Can you guarantee *none* of those devices has any malware—key logger, session hijacker, screen scraper, etc.—installed? Can you guarantee no user will *ever* ignore the certificate warning, enabling a man-in-the-middle attack?

Except for a few of the very largest webmail providers, they probably don't have sufficient security to protect confidential identity data. E.g., if you call them up and say you forgot your password, how do they handle that? Or, if someone *else* calls them up and pretends to be you.

Lastly, even with PGP or S/MIME, you're left with the problem that email, in the real world, can and does get lost. Your site may send a message, get confirmation that the message is accepted for delivery, and then that message just never arrive—not even to a spam folder. That generally isn't acceptable for valuable data.

note: If you encrypt the message with PGP or S/MIME, using sensible settings (e.g., [3072-bit or higher](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57-Part1-revised2_Mar08-2007.pdf) RSA keypair, AES cipher), then it doesn't matter if the email message (ciphertext) is disclosed; it is unreadable without the private key. The crypto used is fairly similar to TLS (but unfortunately doesn't offer things like perfect forward security as its an offline protocol). End-to-end crypto protects against insecurities between the endpoints. Not that I'd advocate printing the cihertext in a newspaper, but even that should still be secure. You must, of course, keep the machine which holds the private key (and decrypts the emails) secure.

Comment: When you are saying "message is stored and transferred in plaintext", that still means the information itself is encrypted using PGP or S/MIME. It'd be helpful to say something about the chances of cracking that encryption, should somebody gain access to the encrypted blob through the "plaintext" storage.

Comment: @deceze: OK, I think I've addressed that in my "note:" paragraph at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Only send the last four digits. Such as !!!!-&&-8590. Send them a secure link to view the Number online if necessary. Also remember that its unlawful in some areas to store Social Security Numbers or any sensitive information in plaintext, always encrypt or encode your data.